# Getting all records with a condition so I can display it in cGridView yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, findall

I have a table used for normalization called Sharing

the contents of the table are share_id, pr_id(patient record id) and doctor_id

I want to get the pr_id under a doctor

so I used this code...

```
$shareModel=Sharing::model()->findByAttributes(array('doctor_id'=>$doctor));
$share= $shareModel->pr_id;
```

then I changed my model from this:

```
$criteria->compare('pr_id',$this->pr_id);
```

into this:

```
$criteria->compare('pr_id',$share);
```

and it worked perfectly! However, when I decided to add more patient records under a single doctor.. it would still only display one record so I had to change the code to this

```
        $shareModel=Sharing::model()->findAll(
                        array(
                                    'condition'=>'doctor_id=:doctor_id', 
                                    'params' => array(':doctor_id' => $doctor)
                                 )
                        );
```

whenever I try to test it using print_r($shareModel), I get the contents that I want but when I add this line

```
$share= $shareModel->pr_id;
```

I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" Error.

can anyone assist?

Comment: Why are you not using relations?

Comment: I guess I don't really know how... sorry beginner here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely get an error because `findAll()` method returns array of objects.

It should be:

```
$share = $shareModel[0]->pr_id;
```

I would strongly recommend you to use model relations and `dataprovider`.